# css: UL and LI should overflow containing TD

Tags: html, css

I have a TD which contains a UL and LIs. I'm trying to get the list to flow outside of the TD. If I use position:absolute all the LIs stack on top of each other. Is there a way to get the LIs to maintain their positioning relative to each other and still flow outside the containing TD?

EDIT Added code (it is written in rails but I've included the generated HTML):

CSS

```
#calendar li {
width: 265px;
 position: absolute;
 background: palegreen;
}
```

Generated HTML

```
<td class="weekend">
    24
     <ul>
    <li>
        Deleware (2)
    </li>
  </ul>
</td>
```

Comment: Code Man. The code. We can come up with the code ourselves in your case but if you provide it, it will show some work from your side!

Comment: The way tables are, they generally don't like their content overflowing them for the most part...

Comment: why would you want content outside of a `td`? Try setting `z-index` to 0 on the table and like 999 on the `ul`

Comment: I realize this is not the ideal html, its generated by a ruby gem that creates a calendar. It generates a TD for each day of the month and a UL LI which contains a meeting. The issue I've run into is I'm trying to find a way to force a meeting spanning more than one day to break out of the TD and span multiple days aka TDs. As well as not have meetings overlap each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reread your explanation and updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/9wc6q/15/). I don't know if you're able to add elements, but you could try wrapping all the `ul`s in a `div` and absolutely positioning the `div`. Here's my CSS:

```
table {
    color: #666;
    font: 16px normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 30px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
}

ul {
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 2;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
    padding: 5px;
}​
```

Comment: Er... my fiddle wasn't rebased >_<

Comment: Yeah this new version works better. This is basically what I was asking for. Unfortunately I think I'm going to have to come up with a more elaborate solution to avoid collisions between meetings spanning multiple days.

Comment: Bummer. Yeah I see what you mean... I updated my fiddle again http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/9wc6q/17/ to try to figure out the collision issue. I'll keep thinking about a non-rails solution.

Comment: Cool thanks. Yeah what you have works great if you know what meetings you're going to have, I'll just need something more dynamic. I have a feeling its going to require some javascript. Let me know if you have any other ideas!

Comment: My buddy and I were thinking that (with JS) ideally you would sort events by length - so that longer events are always on top - and then you would track heights to transpose later events. I'm not sure if that would solve all the edge cases, but that might be a good place to start. Another idea would be to stack based on time of day. Good luck and let me know if you come up with anything clever. I'd be interested.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding

```
position:relative;
```

to the td element.

(like this http://jsfiddle.net/ZGyDW/)

Afaik this is required for the parent element in order to position a child element absolute inside it.

Comment: The problem with this is if you add another UL or another LI in the TD they sit on top of each other.

Comment: maybe i just don't get it, but isn't then relative positioning what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/ZGyDW/4/

Comment: @turbo2oh If you need to stack more than one absolutely positioned `ul`, you will have to explicitly position each `ul`. If you just need the list placed explicitly and you want the `li`s to fall naturally, see below.